# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver when running tests through spring roo

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring

I'm trying to pass the tests automatically generated by roo for the entity classes.  When I run the tests against hsql, they all pass.  But when i run the tests against Oracle, I get the following:

Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:localhost:1521:xe'

I have an oracle db local, I know the connection works.

The ojdbc14.jar file is in the lib directory of JBoss 4.2.3/server/all directory (which is where we're deploying to)

This is the data source bean and entity manager factory definition

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
</bean><!--  Development specific configuration comes here.  -->

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${hibernate.persistenceunit}"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

This is the pom dependency definition:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
        <classifier/>
    </dependency>
```

The persistenceunit variable resolves to persistenceUnitDev

this is the hibernate definition of that persistence unit
    
        org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

And finally my property file that defines the data connection:

```
database.password=password
database.url=jdbc\:localhost\:1521\:xe
database.username=username
database.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I can't figure out why it tells me it can't get a suitable driver.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your URL does not have the proper pattern. Try `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe` instead.

Comment: Yup that was it.  Thank you~!

Comment: Make sure you don't have quotes around the environment vars too. That's what killed me.